# How do i call methods of custom jquery plugin from my own plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I just created my own plugin and i am trying to call another plugin function from it. So i have in my code :

```
<script src='jquery.js'>
<script src='some_other_plugin.js'>
<script src='my_plugin.js'>
```

So when in my plugin i am trying to call some_other_plugins function through $jQuery object - it says that there is no such function... How do i include that plugin so my plugin can see it?

Comment: Could you post a bit more of your code?  Specifically, could you say what plugin you are using and give us the code that isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I FIXED THAT. There was a syntax error in the plugin i wanted to call...